# How to create a Calendar date/picker in ASP.net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, calendar

[image]

My goal is to have a date/picker calendar that will DL a log on the chosen date when the Download Log button is clicked. So far, I have a code that just DLs the todays date. How will manage to control the the date/picker and chose a date and DLs that chosen date with the (Download Log Button)? Thank you..

[image]

Comment: What is the problem with what you have? You should be able to use the date picker control to select any date you want. Put a name attribute on your input and add a parameter to your post method which matches the name of your input box. It should then be passed back to your method on post.

Comment: Post code as text in your question. Using images makes our life harder.

Comment: @RyanWilson Hi, Thanks for the comments is it possible for you to show me the code? I'm basically new to programming. So, the download log button DLs a file. But, I was tasked to add a calendar and if the user pick a date the application will DL a file thats logged for that date. I added a calendar picker and just about it and no logic or what so ever in the back-end. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, change your Method to accept the Date as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Download(DateTime? downloaddate)
```

Add name attribute to your input so that it matches the method parameter name

```
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="downloaddate" style="..."
```

Now when you submit the form, you should get a value in your method if the user selected a date. This does accept a `null` value as the date in the backend method in case the user submits without choosing a date , so you will need to handle this server side. The `DateTime?` is a nullable DateTime

Comment: ok, thank you so much